# Dbcontext creation for multiple server Connections

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbcontext

How to create DbContext manually in Entity Framework for different Database connections?

Answer (score 2):

First you can have multiple named connection strings in **App.Config** file as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ToDoConnectionString" connectionString="data source=myLocalBox;initial catalog=ToDoDbCodeFirst2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="StackOverflowEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=StackOverflow;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now you can define two different custom classes inherited from `DbContext` class (Refer code snipppet):

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EfDevelopment
{
    public class ToDoCodeFirstDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ToDoCodeFirstDbContext()
           : base("name=ToDoConnectionString")//connection string for 1st DB
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ToDo> ToDos { get; set; }
    }

    public class ToDoCodeSecondDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ToDoCodeSecondDbContext()
          : base("name=StackOverflowEntities")//connection string for 2nd DB
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ToDo> ToDos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now inside the main program (I've used console application), instantiate the respective Entity Framework (EF) context class as per your need of connecting them to appropriate database (Refer code snippet):

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              using (var db = new ToDoCodeFirstDbContext())
              {
                  //write your code here for first DB connection
              }

              using (var db = new ToDoCodeSecondDbContext())
             {
                  //write your code here for second DB connection
             }
        }
  }
```